# Jersey - validate REST service parameters

Tags: validation, rest, maven, jersey, jax-rs

is there any tool to simply validate query params using Jersey (and Maven)? I'm trying to do something like this using @NotNull annotation (jersey-bean-validation):

```
@GET
@Path("/count")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response count(@NotNull @QueryParam("my_param") String my_param) {
    //TODO automatically return 400 Bad Request if my_param is null
    return Response.ok("This is a response", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
}
```

I'd like the method to automatically validate query parameters and return 400 Bad Request if no "my_param" is provided.

Comment: Does what you have tried work?

Comment: Not really...adding an annotation @NotNull didn't change the response at all - "return Response.ok()" on the last line was executed.

Comment: Take a look at https://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhaktimehta/archive/2013/10/30/jax-rs-and-bean-validation

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using Jersey 1.x, which does not support annotated validations against PathParams or QueryParams.

See Nick Telfords comments in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/wb6iwrpSrSE