# Resource query parameter validation on jersey-dropwizard

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I have a [dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) application and in one resource i would like to have a required query parameter. I know jersey supports [bean validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) so i tried to use @NotNull annotation but it didn't work. Here's the code to resource:

```
@Path("/resource/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {
    //....constructor...

    @GET
    public String test(
        @PathParam("id") long id,
        @NotNull @QueryParam("required_param") long param) {
        //....
    }
}
```

In case it isn't clear, what i want to happen is whenever the client sends a request without the parameter *required_param* i want to return an error.

After reading the docs i thought maybe dropwizard's configuration would be the reason. So i added this piece of code into my application's run method:

```
environment.jersey().property("jersey.config.disableAutoDiscovery", false);
environment.jersey().property("jersey.config.server.disableAutoDiscovery", false);
environment.jersey().property("jersey.config.beanValidation.disable.server", false);
```

Unfortunately this didn't work either. Anyone has an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Long` object instead of the primitive type?
What version of Jersey are you using? According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090080/jersey-validate-rest-service-parameters `@NotNull` won't work if you're using Jersey 1.x

Comment: I just did and it worked! Thank you very much, i have been trying to solve this for an hour. Could you post an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `Long` object instead of the primitive type?